# Recording audio to internet - SoundCloud API?

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, record, soundcloud

So I need to allow clients to record audio to the internet. Best solution I've found so far which keeps them on our site is the Soundcloud API and I just give them our account details and they use a version of the Soundcloud recorder (Flash/Javascript) hacked together for out site.

Main issue is, these recordings are long. Maybe up to an hour. Because Soundcloud API records in the browser then uploads the audio and transcodes on its server there's a lot to go wrong in the upload process which takes a long time with a big file. It's ok if we just record the audio in say 20 min chunks but it's just not that reliable.

We tried to build our own using wami-recorder, but that meant transcoding from wav to MP3 in the browser before upload to make the file smaller, but taking more time on the client machine - at least Soundcloud does the transcoding server-side.

Given the size of the files should I be looking at a server side recorder/streaming solution based on red5 or something, or is a client side recorder with upload a better proposal?

thanks a lot!

Comment: There are lots of possible solutions to this problem. For example, a solution you didn't mention is that you can even stream the audio durring recording to a server. Which is "best" depends on your needs and capabilities. Are you recording music, speech, etc. Do clients have broadband? reliable internet? etc.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this that you can share?